# Where in the $\Sigma_α^β$ hierarchy does the problem of deciding a sentence in ZFC fall?

Tags: set-theory, computability

Where in the hierarchy $\Sigma_α^β$ does the problem of deciding the truth value of a sentence in ZFC fall?

Answer (score 8):

A sentence doesn't have a truth value in a theory (such as ZFC).  What you can ask about a sentence relative to ZFC is whether that sentence is *provable* or *not provable* in ZFC.

The question of whether a sentence is provable in ZFC is $\Sigma^0_1$; in other words, the set of provable sentences is recursively enumerable.